# bigquery converting string to time mm:ss

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

how can I convert the string "average_time_per_KM" to time in the formt of mm:ss?
I tryed using TIME and got an error 'Invalid time string "4:56"'[Cast query to time format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL7V2.png)

is there a different function to cast in to mm:ss?

Comment: It is better with the sample input and desired ouput.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of below parse time that presented as string as `minutes:seconds`

```
PARSE_TIME("%M:%S", average_time_per_KM)
```

or

```
CAST(average_time_per_KM AS TIME FORMAT 'MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell BQ what is the meaning of each digit in the string you give it.
For that you need to use the `PARSE_TIME` function:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIME("%M:%S", average_time_per_KM)
FROM `your.table`
```